# how to process Route 404page such as "/search/:searchText" in react-route-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
function App() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path={"/"} element={<Home />} />
          <Route path={`/page/:menu`} element={<MovieMenu />} />
          <Route path={`/movie/:id`} element={<Detail />} />
          <Route path={`/search/:searchText`} element={<Search />} />
          <Route path={"*"} element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}
```

If i process 404 page in the above way, `/` handle it well, but `<NotFound />` not be rendered if any path is entered after `/page/fldlfsd;lf;` or `/search/dsklfskldf`. Is there a way?

Comment: Use the `useParams` hook in the routed components to access the path params and validate them. If they are invalid then redirect to the `NotFound` route. Can you share an example if these routed components and what they do with the params?

Comment: @Drew Reese Is the path `NotFound` "*"? I don't know where to specify the redirect path.

Comment: You can use any path that isn't specifically handled. You could also define a `"/404"` route and redirect unhandled paths there. In other words, `<Route path={"/404"} element={<NotFound />} />`, and `<Route path={"*"} element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />`, and then anywhere in your code you can issue an imperative redirect to `"/404"` (i.e. `navigate("/404", { replace: true })`) in the pages that get bad path param values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths like `"/page/fldlfsd;lf;"` and `"/search/dsklfskldf"` will be matched and rendered by the `Routes` component. The route param validation needs to occur in the routed component.

Each component can use the `useParams` hook to access the route param, validate it, and redirect to the `NotFound` route if param is invalid.

To help with this I suggest creating a discrete route to render `NotFound` so you can imperatively redirect to it from components and create a redirect route to handle unknown routes.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/page/:menu" element={<MovieMenu />} />
          <Route path="/movie/:id" element={<Detail />} />
          <Route path="/search/:searchText" element={<Search />} />
          <Route path="/404" element={<NotFound />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}
```

...

MovieMenu

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { menu } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  ... logic to validate menu param ...
  if (invalidMenu) {
    navigate("/404", { replace: true });
  }
}, [menu, navigate]);

...
```